# perl one liner + print VALUE in the end of the line

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl, ksh

The following perl one liner checks if `$CURRENT_VERSION` matches `$NEW_VERSION` exactly, and prints it if it does.

Example:

```
CURRENT_VERSION=223.3.12.4.5.3
NEW_VERSION=223.3.12.4.5.3
DATE=17.3.2013
```

```
echo $CURRENT_VERSION  | \
  perl -ne 'BEGIN { $STR = shift(@ARGV); } print if /\Q$STR\E/; ' $NEW_VERSION 
223.3.12.4.5.3
```

What do I need to add to the perl one liner to print the `$DATE` value at the end of the line?

For example:

```
CURRENT_VERSION=223.3.12.4.5.3
NEW_VERSION=223.3.12.4.5.3
DATE=17.3.2013
```

```
echo $CURRENT_VERSION  | \
  perl -ne'BEGIN { $STR = shift(@ARGV); } print if /\Q$STR\E/; ' \
  $NEW_VERSION < add syntax to  print $DATE > 
223.3.12.4.5.3  17.3.2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -F= -lane '$v{$F[0]}=$F[1]; if ($F[0] eq "DATE") {$v{CURRENT_VERSION} eq $v{NEW_VERSION} ? print $v{NEW_VERSION}, " ", $v{DATE} : exit(1)}'
```

Or, still a one-liner, but readable

```
perl -F= -lane '
    $v{$F[0]} = $F[1];
    if ($F[0] eq "DATE") {
        $v{CURRENT_VERSION} eq $v{NEW_VERSION} 
            ? print $v{NEW_VERSION}, " ", $v{DATE} 
            : exit(1)
    }' << END
CURRENT_VERSION=223.3.12.4.5.3
NEW_VERSION=223.3.12.4.5.3
DATE=17.3.2013
END
```

outputs

```
223.3.12.4.5.3 17.3.2013
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo $CURRENT_VERSION | \
    perl -e '($nv,$d)=(shift,shift); /\Q$nv/ and chomp,print "$_ $d\n" while <>' $NEW_VERSION $DATE
```

However, it might be better to include $CURRENT_VERSION as one of the parameters as well:

```
perl -e '($nv,$d,$cv)=@ARGV; $cv=~/\Q$nv/ and print "$cv $d\n"' $NEW_VERSION $DATE $CURRENT_VERSION
```

Comment: what about the "Q$STR\E" , I dont see \E in your syntax ?

Comment: @yael: If there is nothing after the `\E`, you can ommit it.